# Can't find Variable : "View"

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, frontend

beginners question. The error says it can't find a variable: "View"

I have written this code in order to integrate a design to my code but it is giving: "can't find variable: View " what am I missing

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from "react-native" ;




export default class MenuButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View menu={burger.menuIcon}>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const burger = StyleSheet.create({
    menuIcon: {
color    : 'rgba(255,255,255,0.0)',
  top                 : 17 ,
  height              : 5 ,
  width               : 6 ,
  position            : 'absolute' ,
  margin              : 0,
  left                : 26 

}});
```

I expect a blank screen with no errors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add view to the import like this:

```
import {StyleSheet,View} from "react-native" ;
```

Comment: It was in all my other files except this one how did I miss that... Thanks for the answer

Comment: @CamilleBasbous great mate. if you think this is the true answer only press the tick at the bottom of the answer to make it green.